# How to query every users data in Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

My goal is to create an admin dashboard to see all the users data in 1 place.

Right now, my Firestore collection hierarchy is:

- forms

  - UID of user 1

    - form

      - form id
        - name, etc
  - UID of user 2

    - form

      - form id
        - name, etc
      - form id
        - name, etc

I want to get all the data of name, etc, across every users in Firestore. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

In your case something like the following should work:

```
firebase.firestore()
  .collectionGroup('form')
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    // do something with documents
    console.log(documents);
  });
```